# Unity application running but not responding

Tags: unity, launcher, gimp

I'm quite confused and not sure how to exactly describe the issue, but I'll start with the statement that everything was fine for over a week (since I actually started using Ubuntu) until 30 minutes ago.

When I started Gimp, it showed up on the launcher bar, but it wasn't responding at all. The launcher looks as below:

[image]

You can see a sort of empty arrow next to Gimp. When I click it nothing happens,
when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> it's not brought to front. I've tried reinstalling it, but that didn't help.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The application is definitely running, and probably correctly.

There are a few possibilities:

1. you have a second screen connected, but it is switched off.
2. you have workspaces enabled, and `Gimp` is running on one of your other workspaces / viewports.

In the first case, either disconnect the screen or switch it on to see the application window.
In the second case, navigate through the other workspaces with the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ up/down/left/right arrow keys.

#### Note

In some occasions, after unplugging a second monitor, the monitor still appears as a "phantom" monitor in System Settings > Displays, causing the same issues as above. In that case, switching it off in display settings should solve the issues.

Comment: It's dumb, but I actually have a second screen and it actually was switched off. Thanks!

Comment: @Nhor Easy to forget. I have an external monitor for testing purposes and forget it .... all the time :)